# How to initialize bidirectional graph in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

I have some classes that create a graph with "back pointers". I tried to make the back pointers `unowned` (they'd create cycles otherwise) and initialize them in my `init()`, but that creates problems with `self` references. How am I supposed to get around this?

```
class Parent {
    var child1:Child
    var child2:Child
    unowned var myOwner:Thing

    init(myOwner:Thing) {
        child1 = Child(parent: self) // Compiler errors here
        child2 = Child(parent: self) // and here
        self.myOwner = myOwner
    }
}

class Child {
    unowned var parent:Parent

    init(parent:Parent) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
'self' used before all all stored properties are initialized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that error because Swift enforces that all variables must have a value before you can use `self` to avoid your instance not being fully initialised. In your case you have two options:

**1.** Mark `child1` and `child2` as implicitly unwrapped optionals:

```
 class Parent {
    var child1: Child!
    var child2: Child!
    unowned var myOwner:Thing

    init(myOwner:Thing) {
        // Note - myOwner is being set before the children.
        self.myOwner = myOwner

        child1 = Child(parent: self) 
        child2 = Child(parent: self) 
    }
}
```

This results in no errors because both `child1` and `child2` have a default value of `nil`, which you are then changing in `init`.

**2.** Use `lazy` instantiation:

```
class Parent {
    lazy var child1: Child = Child(parent: self)
    lazy var child2: Child = Child(parent: self)
    unowned var myOwner:Thing

    init(myOwner:Thing) {
        self.myOwner = myOwner
    }
}
```

This results in no errors because a `lazy` property's value is only calculated when it is first used, therefore `self` is guaranteed to have been fully initialised.

Hope that helps.

Comment: lazy FTW. Worked like a charm.